# Plone: Shown default views on navtree

Tags: plone

My question is quite simple....

In Plone 4 (4.2) what I need to setup to make a default view, for example a simple page, to be shown in the navigation tree.

[image: doesn't show default view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also create a link in the folder, set destination to './idOfPage1' and set the link as defaultview of the folder.

Users without editing-rights will be redirected to Page1 then and the page itself will be shown in the navportlet.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation tree uses the `INavigationQueryBuilder` component to find all elements shown. The default implementation *filters out* anything used as a default page.

You'll have to provide your own implementation instead; but you can re-use the original implementation. All you have to do is alter the generated query a little; normally, if no more specific query is present, the `is_default_page` index is used to filter out default pages. But if your *altered* query adds a search for that index, then it'll not try to add a more specific filter. Setting it to search for `(True, False)` means it'll return both default and non-default pages, effectively neutralizing the filter.

The implementation then becomes:

```
from plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation import QueryBuilder, INavigationPortlet
from zope.component import adapts
from zope.interface import implements, Interface


class INonDefaultPageFilteringNavigationPortlet(INavigationPortlet):
    pass


class DontFilterDefaultQueryBuilder(QueryBuilder):
    implements(INavigationQueryBuilder)
    adapts(Interface, INavigationPortlet)

    def __init__(self, context, portlet):
        super(DontFilterDefaultQueryBuilder, self).__init__(context, portlet)
        self.query['is_default_page'] = (True, False)  # Don't filter out default pages
```

You'll have to register this as an adapter, *and* add the `INonDefaultPageFilteringNavigationPortlet` to your portlet to 'activate' this builder:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five">

<adapter factory=".yourmodule.DontFilterDefaultQueryBuilder" />

<five:implements
    class="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.Assignment"
    interface=".yourmodule.INonDefaultPageFilteringNavigationPortlet" />

</configure>
```

All with the caveat that this is untested, but it *should* work.